# Keras ImportError: cannot import name initializations

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Error:

```
(tensorflow) jcsu@jcsu:~$ python
Python 2.7.13 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> from keras import initializations
Using TensorFlow backend.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name initializations
```

Similar error occurred when I tried to import `time_distributed_dense` from `keras.layers.recurrent`.

Anybody please help me?

Comment: what is the version of keras that you are using?

Comment: @anonyXmous  `conda list` shows 2.0.3

Comment: try `import keras`; `keras.__version__`.  what does that return

Comment: @putonspectacles   Tried, also 2.0.3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Keras 2.0,  `initializations` was [renamed](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/commit/f2fe51a9d2bc9d228e3ac374579e87595f51fef6#diff-4ea1eab272323ecb1f250db1b8d83443) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170423194054/https://github.com/fchollet/keras/commit/f2fe51a9d2bc9d228e3ac374579e87595f51fef6)) as `initializers`. You should therefore instead write

```
from keras import initializers
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just ran into another similar problem: `ImportError: cannot import name time_distributed_dense`. So what is the new name for `time_distributed_dense`?